# How do you compare strings in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to do String1 =< String2 for a sort.

I can't find this anywhere.  And obviously String1 =< String2. didn't work when I tried it.

I'd appreciate any help, I'm almost done with project due in 2 hours and this has held me up for the past forever (it feels like it has).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `String1 =< String2` to `String1 @=< String2`

Example:

```
?- abc @=< abc.
```